# Как прервать цикл foreach и начать с того же прерванного шага?

Tags: php

Необходимо прервать цикл foreach, обернуть в <tr> и начать с того же места. При другом цикле я бы просто сделал счетчик и потом просто начал с того же номера, а тут не могу сообразить, как это сделать. После пяти итераций надо <td> в <tr> переместить. Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот участок кода.

```
<div class="attr-wrapper">
                      <?php if($product['attribute_groups']) { ?>
                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <?php foreach($product['attribute_groups'] as $attribute_group) { ?>

                              <?php foreach($attribute_group['attribute'] as $attribute) { ?>
                                  <?php if($attribute['text']!='') { ?>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php echo $attribute['name']; ?>: <?php echo $attribute['text']; ?>
                                    </td>
                                  <?php } ?>
                              <?php } ?>

                            <?php } ?>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      <?php } ?>
        </div><!-- .attr-wrapper -->
```

Comment: а вы не прерывайте цикл, вы внутри него поставьте условие, при котором нужно закрыть старый tr и открыть новый

Comment: Вы можете показать, как это реализовать в данном примере?

Comment: @harley, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед циклом: `<?$k=0;?>`

В начале цикла: `<?if(++$k%5==0):?> </tr><tr><?endif;?>`